# An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I wanted to get some data from my **WEB API** but i got error message like this in API debug console:

```
 fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint WebAPI_1.Controllers.DataCTXController.Get (WebAPI_1) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.
Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code. The call to app.UseAuthorization() must appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.ThrowMissingAuthMiddlewareException(Endpoint endpoint)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I used **Postman** to send request. I tried to moving app.UseAuthorization() between lines and figuring something on my own but still nothing so that's why I need your's help. Here is my Startup.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebAPI_1.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace WebAPI_1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(s => s.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default1")));

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMvc(services => services.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

            services.AddCors();

            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(Options =>
            {
                Options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
              endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "defaultApi", template: "api/{controller}/{action}");
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the exception is self-explanatory,

> Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code. The call to app.UseAuthorization() must appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...)

You need to add

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

in Configure method.

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); // Add it here
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i missed "app.UseAuthentication();"